Why does my update query not updating the timestamp properly?
I am trying to update two columns in my database. Earlier it was working fine but now it is just updating the timestamp as 2022-06-02 00:00:00.000 where the date is getting updated but not the time. Moreover values are coming in fine in params but still not updating the db properly. I am not sure what is wrong with it or what am I missing. Please help
async deleteById<T>(params: DeletedBy): Promise<IResult<T> | undefined> {
        try {
            if (params.id) {
                const request = new mssql.Request();
                request.input('id', mssql.UniqueIdentifier, params.id);
                request.input('deletedBy', mssql.Int, params.deletedBy);
                const dbResult = await request.query<T>(`
                    UPDATE 
                        ${this.tableName}
                    SET
                        deletedBy = @deletedBy,
                        deletedAt = GETDATE()
                    WHERE
                        id = @id
                `);
                console.log('This is the query runnning', `
                UPDATE 
                        ${this.tableName}
                    SET
                        deletedBy = @deletedBy,
                        deletedAt = GETDATE()
                    WHERE
                        id = @id
            `)
                return dbResult;
            }
        } catch (e) {
           console.log('restoreById', e);
            throw new ApiError(500, 'restoreById not working');
        }
    }

I am using mssql version ^6.3.1
I have tried to update the inbuilt function, and again tried to update the timestamp by updating through typescript sysdate, as well but it was not updating properly.
I tried running the query manually on the db. It seems to be working fine
the columns are updated as follows
deletedAt: 2024-06-02 00:00:00.000
it should be updating as
deletedAt: 2024-06-02 13:45:37.140

This sounds like the deletedAt column might have the wrong type.

It is of DATETIME2, and if I try to run the same query manually in db with the hard coded values of deletedBy and @d. It works fine

try:
import * as mssql from 'mssql';

interface DeletedBy {
    id: string;
    deletedBy: number;
}

interface IResult<T> {
    recordset: T[];
    rowsAffected: number[];
    output: { [key: string]: any };
}

class ApiError extends Error {
    constructor(public statusCode: number, message: string) {
        super(message);
        this.name = 'ApiError';
    }
}

class MyDatabaseClass {
    private tableName: string;
    private pool: mssql.ConnectionPool;

    constructor(tableName: string, pool: mssql.ConnectionPool) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.pool = pool;
    }

    async deleteById<T>(params: DeletedBy): Promise<IResult<T> | undefined> {
        try {
            if (params.id) {
                // Ensure the connection pool is connected
                await this.pool.connect();

                const request = this.pool.request();

                // Get the current timestamp and log it
                const currentTimestamp = new Date();
                console.log('Current Timestamp:', currentTimestamp);

                // Format the timestamp explicitly
                const formattedTimestamp = currentTimestamp.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
                console.log('Formatted Timestamp:', formattedTimestamp);

                request.input('id', mssql.UniqueIdentifier, params.id);
                request.input('deletedBy', mssql.Int, params.deletedBy);
                request.input('deletedAt', mssql.DateTime, formattedTimestamp);

                const query = `
                    UPDATE 
                        ${this.tableName}
                    SET
                        deletedBy = @deletedBy,
                        deletedAt = @deletedAt
                    WHERE
                        id = @id
                `;

                console.log('Executing query:', query);
                const dbResult = await request.query<T>(query);

                return dbResult;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('deleteById error:', e);
            throw new ApiError(500, 'deleteById not working');
        } finally {
            // Ensure the pool is closed after the operation to prevent memory leaks
            await this.pool.close();
        }
    }
}

// Usage example
(async () => {
    const config: mssql.config = {
        user: 'your_db_user',
        password: 'your_db_password',
        server: 'your_db_server',
        database: 'your_db_name',
        options: {
            encrypt: true, // For Azure SQL
            enableArithAbort: true
        }
    };

    const pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(config);
    const myDatabaseClass = new MyDatabaseClass('your_table_name', pool);

    try {
        const result = await myDatabaseClass.deleteById<{ id: string }>({
            id: 'your_id',
            deletedBy: 1
        });
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();


still the same thing. It stores the value as 2022-06-02 00:00:00.000

Please provide an explanation of your change

It is not working. Also, I have tried working by creating a sp and then executing it, that is also not working. It keeps on updating the value like this 2022-06-02 00:00:00.000

async deleteById<T>(params: DeletedBy): Promise<IResult<T> | undefined> {
        try {
            if (params.id) {
                const request = new mssql.Request();
                request.input('id', mssql.UniqueIdentifier, params.id);
                request.input('deletedBy', mssql.Int, params.deletedBy);
                
                // Pass the current date and time directly
                request.input('deletedAt', mssql.DateTime2, new Date()); 

                const dbResult = await request.query<T>(`
                    UPDATE 
                        ${this.tableName}
                    SET
                        deletedBy = @deletedBy,
                        deletedAt = GETDATE()
                    WHERE
                        id = @id
                `);
                console.log('This is the query runnning', `
                UPDATE 
                        ${this.tableName}
                    SET
                        deletedBy = @deletedBy,
                        deletedAt = GETDATE()
                    WHERE
                        id = @id
            `)
                return dbResult;
            }
        } catch (e) {
           console.log('restoreById', e);
            throw new ApiError(500, 'restoreById not working');
        }
    }


I tried this as well, and with moment as well. But still gives the same thing

Please provide an explanation of your change
